# OKPAY Payment Gateway: Integration Guide

Tags: payment-gateway

I need to integrate okPay with my website but I am not able to find testing details so that I can check whether code is working fine or not. Can you please suggest where can I start or is there any other way for same? I have placed below code

```
 <form action="https://www.okpay.com/process.html" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="ok_receiver" value="XXXXXX">
      <input type="hidden" name="ok_item_1_name" value="test">
      <input type="hidden" name="ok_currency" value="usd">
      <input type="hidden" name="ok_item_1_price" value="0.01">
      <input type="submit" value="Payment"> 
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Payment Integration Guide](https://dev.okpay.com/en/guides/accepting-payments.html), section 6, you would request a test account to for final testing with the links below.

> §6. Final Testing of Payment Processing
>   As we explained in [Testing Your IPN Handler](https://dev.okpay.com/en/guides/accepting-payments.html#ipn_testing), you can check the basic operation of your handler by using the offered IPN simulation service.
>
> In addition, for final and more complete testing of your code as well as business-logic operation, you may need additional real world testing with real clients and OKPAY system replies.
>
> We recommend that you create a test account under the name of your developer which can be used to perform test payments. You can temporarily amend the price of your goods/services to $0.01 USD for this puprose.
>
> If you have any questions or problems feel free to contact [OKPAY Support  Service](https://support.okpay.com/en/index.html). Our technicians are happy to assist you.